# question got migrated from stackoverflow to superuser. what should i do? repost?

Tags: support, migration

I got a question that got migrated from SO to SP.

what do i do after that? repost?

look for the migrated question?

can somebody do a slightly detailed explanation with good examples what type of questions should be posted to which website? :S

Comment: Releveant question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327183/i-restricted-a-blogspot-account-readers-to-just-its-authors-so-i-cannot-use-goog

Comment: That question belongs on Super User.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/29311/i-restricted-a-blogspot-account-readers-to-just-its-authors-so-i-cannot-use-goog

Answer (score 5):

When you click on the Migrated to link it will take you to the question on the new site. You can then follow it from there. (The superuser part in the bit below points to the new location for the question)

```
migrated to superuser.com 1 hour ago
```

This particular question already has some answers on SU and I have also edited it to be more accurate. Your reputation earned from this point forward will count towards your SU reputation.

The migration process is discussed in detail [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/migrate-questions-between-websites/) on the StackOverflow Blog.

Answer (score 3):

You should search for the migrated question. If you have enough reputation on the new site, you can vote to migrate it back. You can repost the question with some rewording to make it fitting for the page selected. There is a link on the closed question to the new one to follow and find it.

What are acceptable questions on each site? You find that information on each site's FAQ:

- meta

> If your question is about:
>
> Stack Overflow Server Fault Super User
>   ... it is welcome here. No question is
>   too trivial or too "newbie".

- StackOverflow (SO)

> Programming questions, of course! As
>   long as your question is:
>
> detailed and specific written clearly
>   and simply of interest to at least one
>   other programmer somewhere ... it is
>   welcome here. No question is too
>   trivial or too "newbie". Oh yes, and
>   it should be about programming. You
>   know, with a computer.

- Serverfault (SF)

> Server Fault is for system
>   administrators and IT professionals,
>   people who manage or maintain
>   computers in a professional capacity.
>   If you are in charge of ...
>
> servers networks many desktop PCs
>   (other than your own) ... then you're
>   in the right place to ask your
>   question! Well, as long as the
>   question is about your servers, your
>   networks, or desktops you support,
>   anyway.
>
> Please note that Server Fault is not
>   for general computer troubleshooting
>   questions; if you paid for that
>   desktop hardware, and it's your
>   personal workstation, it is unlikely
>   that your question is appropriate for
>   Server Fault.

- Superuser (SU)

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts
>   and power users. If you have a
>   question about ...
>
> computer hardware computer software …
>   and it is not about videogames or
>   consoles, then you're in the right
>   place to ask your question!

I strongly feel that questions can be posted on multiple sites, if you expect to get corresponding answers from different communities. see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/what-to-do-with-cross-site-duplicates/4712#4712).